# increase weight between relationship on finding match - cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query in cypher , I create a relationship between :

```html
MATCH match (u:user {id : "10662"})-[r:has_profile]->(p:profile)
  , (u2:user)-[r2:has_profile]->(p2:profile)
WHERE
  p.user_id <> p2.user_id 
AND  abs(u2.date_birth - u.date_birth) >= 94608000000
merge u-[r:matches_with { weight: rand() }]->u2
RETURN collect(u2.id) as id;
```

In this particular situation, I am trying to create a relationship between u and u2 only on a match, when a previous relationship between u and u2 is found. It will just increment the weight in the relationship. 
And I am trying to return the matches based on weight.

Can someone please suggest an approach for incrementing the weight on finding a match, with this query. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that looks for all `matches_with` relationships starting from a specific `user`, increments the weight of the relationship, and returns the results sorted by weight.

```
MATCH (u:user { id : "10662" })-[r:matches_with]->(u2)
SET r.weight = r.weight + 1
RETURN u, r, u2
ORDER BY r.weight;
```

Comment: if my query runs for the first time, it runs 10 matches_with relationship. If I run the query again instead of adding weight, it again generates 10 more matches. I am trying to find out how we can avoid recreating matches_with relationship , in every match.

Comment: The query in your question is not legal, since it references an undefined `p` variable. Please provide your actual query.

Comment: I changed the original query to incorporate the parameters. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I found a mechanism , by which you can alter the weight..
I added the merge clause before the return statement:

```html
MATCH (u:user { id : "10662" })-[r:matches_with]->(u2)

  merge (u)-[m:matches_with]->(u2)
 SET m.weight= 
  CASE WHEN NOT (HAS (m.weight)) 
    THEN toFloat(0.125)
  ELSE  LAST(m.weight)/2 
  END

RETURN u.id, m, u2.id
ORDER BY m.weight;
```

Thank you @cybersam.

Comment: you can also use `ON CREATE SET m.weight = 0.125 ON MATCH SET m.weight = m.weight  / 2.0`